# Rails attachment on polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, polymorphic-associations, rails-models

I've tried many, many things so I'm not even sure which code/errors to give. I'll give my most generic code.

Models: Job, Attachment
Attachment - polymorphic association through attachable

Job Model

```
has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
```

Attachment Model

```
belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
```

Job View

```
= simple_form_for(@job, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true }) do |f|
= f.fields_for :attachable do |a|
  = a.file_field :file_url
= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary offset1'
```

Job Controller

```
def update
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
if @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
```

It fails when I hit submit. With different errors depending on how I try to do it. With this code I posted I get Unkown Attribute: Attachable.

I've tried many, many different things (fields_for :attachment(s), different model options, etc), but I really need some help now.

Comment: What error do you get when  you do `fields_for :attachment`?  Can you post that log.

Comment: I get unknown attribute: attachment on the @job.update_attributes line

Answer (score 2):

`@job` has `:attachments`, not `:attachable`. If `@job` does not currently have any attachments, you will need to provide one. Try instead:

```
= simple_form_for(@job, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true}) do |f|

  - # form for existing attachments
  %strong Attachments
  = simple_fields_for :attachments do |a|
    = a.input :file_url

  - # form for a new attachment
  %strong Add Attachment
  = f.simple_fields_for :attachments, @job.attachments.build do |a|
    = a.input :file_url

  = f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary offset1'
```

Comment: When I do this, the form doesn't render. Does not show up in HTML at all.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to account for the missing fields. If the job doesn't have attachments yet, you need to provide one to the `simple_fields_for` or `fields_for` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Job has many attachments, not just one. Also, the relation is called attachments, not attachable (the "as" option passed is just to let know Rails which is the mirror relation). The form should look like this:

```
= simple_form_for(@job, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true }) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :attachments do |a|
    = a.file_field :file_url
  = f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary offset
```

**Edit:**
The form won't display any attachment until you build one or more with "@job.attachments.build". Another alternative is to use a gem for nested forms like the following https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form .

Comment: When I do this, the form doesn't render. Does not show up in HTML at all.

Comment: @mattt- Added some clarification to the answer.